# cant load worlds with gazebo v8.0.0

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros-kinetic-desktop-full and ros-kinetic-turtlebot-* on an Arch Linux. and when i try to run the "roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch" it launches with no errors but the world only contains the turtlebot,ground,a light source and no other playground.world objects.

[image: image description]

I can confirm gazebo loads the world correctly when i run "gazebo ./playground.world" and loads all the objects except the turtlebot.

[image: image description]

some maybe related packages versions:
gazebo v8.0.0
protobuf 3.2.0
ros-kinetic-gazebo-* 2.5.8

logs: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rda98ftecojbc4g/AADkllj93GMG1rf29z0YumRUa?dl=0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258117/cant-load-worlds-with-gazebo-v8.0.0/) by [mak](https://answers.ros.org/users/29855/mak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-03-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mak](https://answers.ros.org/users/29855/mak/) on 2017-03-30**:
tried gazebo8_ros_pkgs (kinetic) - 2.5.10-1 but the results is the same.wondering whether I am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out I can successfully load world by running

```
roscore &
rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world 
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

Even though I see this error

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver: line 37: 17949 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)     GAZEBO_MASTER_URI="$desired_master_uri" gzserver $final[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 17754, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/mak/.ros/log/4b042878-1643-11e7-9ed2-681729def242/gazebo-1.log].log file: /home/mak/.ros/log/4b042878-1643-11e7-9ed2-681729def242/gazebo-1*.log
```

while running roslaunch above, world loads correctly and I can run simulation

[image: image description]

It's not the solution I was looking for... but at least it's working for now.

---

Originally posted by [mak](https://answers.ros.org/users/29855/mak/) with karma: 36 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1